# How to classify percentages by category in R

Tags: r, percentage, tapply

Input

```
titanic <- read.csv("http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/titanic3.csv")
names(titanic)
tbl <- table(titanic$survived)
cbind(tbl, prop.table(tbl))
```

Desired Output: Percentage survival categorized by gender, eg. `titanic$sex`.

My attempt:

```
tapply(titanic$survived, titanic$sex, table)
```

This gets me a gender breakdown of survival by raw numbers;

```
$female
0   1 
127 339 

$male
 0   1 
682 161
```

but how do I get a breakdown by percentages? Ie, the desired output:

```
$female
0   1 
.27 .72 

$male
0   1 
.81 .19
```

Comment: `tapply(titanic$survived, titanic$sex, function(x) 100*table(x)/length(x))`

Comment: Or `aggregate(survived~sex,titanic,function(x)prop.table(table(x)))`

Comment: `prop.table( table(titanic[c("sex","survived")]), 1)`

Comment: See this tutorial http://trevorstephens.com/post/72920580937/titanic-getting-started-with-r-part-2-the It uses an approach similar to @Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate the specific form you asked for:

```
lapply(split(titanic,titanic$sex),function(x)prop.table(table(x$survived)))
# $female
# 
#         0         1 
# 0.2725322 0.7274678 
# 
# $male
# 
#         0         1 
# 0.8090154 0.1909846
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `prop.table` function

```
> prop.table(table(titanic$survived, titanic$sex), 2)

       female      male
  0 0.2725322 0.8090154
  1 0.7274678 0.1909846
```

Passing in 1 gives the percentages based on the sex instead.